# scaling a service with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I am facing issues with scaling a service using docker compose and need help.

Below is what I have:

1. My docker-compose.yml

`web:
    image: nginx`

2. The command that I use to run:

`docker-compose -f compose/nginx-docker-compose.yml scale web=3 up -d`

3. The output of the command:

`Creating and starting compose_web_1 ... done
Creating and starting compose_web_2 ... done
Creating and starting compose_web_3 ... done
ERROR: Arguments to scale should be in the form service=num`

4. The output of `docker ps -a`

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fead93372574        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp     compose_web_3
de110ae9606d        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp     compose_web_1
4d7f8fd39ccd        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp     compose_web_2`

5. I should also mention that when I do not use the `scale web=3` option, the service comes up just fine.
6. docker version

`Client:
Version:      1.10.3
API version:  1.22
Go version:   go1.5.3
Git commit:   20f81dd
Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:51:19 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

`Server:
Version:      1.10.3
API version:  1.22
Go version:   go1.5.3
Git commit:   20f81dd
Built:        Thu Mar 10 15:51:19 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

7. `docker-compose version`

`docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`

Let me know if anybody else has face this and have found a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the "**up**" if you use scale option. For ex: **docker-compose scale web=3**. 
Let's see [document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/) from Docker site.
In your case:

```
docker-compose -f compose/nginx-docker-compose.yml scale web=3 up -d
```

The command may "think" that the **up** is the service name needed to be scaled (should be up=3). So it threw the warning like that